# Grep with redirect is giving null byte

Tags: grep, binary, nul

My grep command is generating a NUL byte at the end of its output.

I have `file.xml` which contains only:

```
<Game>
    <Player p1="Bob"/>
    <Player p2="Fred"/>
</Game>
```

Now running `grep -Pzo '<Game>(\n|.)*?(</Game>)'` gives the expected output:

```
<Game>
        <Player p1="Bob"/>
        <Player p2="Fred"/>
</Game>
```

But redirecting the output with `grep -Pzo '<Game>(\n|.)*?(</Game>)' file.xml > out.md` shows the NUL byte at the end of the file when opened in Notepad++ & opens as a binary file in Sublime:

```
3c47 616d 653e 0a09 3c50 6c61 7965 7220
7031 3d22 426f 6222 2f3e 0a09 3c50 6c61
7965 7220 7032 3d22 4672 6564 222f 3e0a
3c2f 4761 6d65 3e00
```

This doesn't happen with other grep commands such as `grep -rlF "Game" > out.md`.

Comment: The output of `out.md` is verbatim of `file.xml` is (same exact hash `d99112cdc552a9574303773265356513f45145ff`). The problem is obviously elsewhere, and `grep` is not the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which platform and grep version using, but I would just omit the -z option:

From [GNU grep 3.0 doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Other-Options.html#Other-Options):

```
-z--null-data   
Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the -Z or --null option, this option can be used with commands like ‘sort -z’ to process arbitrary file names.
```

HEX of file.xml:

```
0000000: 3c47 616d 653e 0a20 2020 203c 506c 6179  <Game>.    <Play
0000010: 6572 2070 313d 2242 6f62 222f 3e0a 2020  er p1="Bob"/>.
0000020: 2020 3c50 6c61 7965 7220 7032 3d22 4672    <Player p2="Fr
0000030: 6564 222f 3e0a 3c2f 4761 6d65 3e0a       ed"/>.</Game>.
```

So running:

```
grep -Po '<Game>(\n|.)*?(</Game>)' file.xml > out.md
```

HEX of out.md:

```
0000000: 3c47 616d 653e 0a20 2020 203c 506c 6179  <Game>.    <Play
0000010: 6572 2070 313d 2242 6f62 222f 3e0a 2020  er p1="Bob"/>.
0000020: 2020 3c50 6c61 7965 7220 7032 3d22 4672    <Player p2="Fr
0000030: 6564 222f 3e0a 3c2f 4761 6d65 3e0a       ed"/>.</Game>.
```